# Is there a 64 bit version of Office for Mac / OSX?

Tags: microsoft-office, 64-bit

I notice that the current version of Office for Mac includes VBA7. Which is required for the MS implementation of Win64 / 64 bit Office for Windows.

Does that mean there is now a 64 bit version of Office for Mac?

Comment: Easier to answer this question if you provide the exact build of Office you have installed

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have a version of Office installed. I don't even have a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***All*** current macOS apps are 64-bit. 32-bit was phased out starting in 2007 & from 2019 all 32-bit support was finally dropped. 32-bit apps, libraries etc will no longer run on any Mac.

I'm not sure when the first fully 64-bit Office was released; but somewhere between those dates.